# IDE Rider. How to disable moving the carriage on new line when I press Shift + Enter?

Tags: autocomplete, ide, settings, jetbrains-ide, rider

May be someone know how I can disable the following behaviour: when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - Rider moves the carriage on new line.

For example I write:

```
if (someCondition){[Here I press Shift+ENTER]}
```

I want:

```
if (someCondition)
{
| <- carriage
}
```

But Rider makes:

```
if (someCondition){}
| <- carriage is here
```

Comment: Why not just press `Enter` -- it should do just that. Other than that -- `Settings /Preferences | Keymap` and check what actions have `Ctrl + Enter` as shortcut (there is a button next to search field that allows such lookup)

Comment: Sorry, I mean Shift + Enter. Shift I must hold when I want to type "{" and sometime when I type fast I take holded Shift and press Enter. I checked KeyMap and didn't find something about Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`
2. Use `Find Actions by Shortcut`button to find what actions have <kbd>Shift + Enter</kbd> assigned to them.
3. Remove that shortcut from appropriate action(s)

Here in PhpStorm (it would be similar in Rider as they both IDEA-based IDEs) <kbd>Shift + Enter</kbd> is assigned to `Editor Actions | Start New Line` action in Default keymap that behaves as per your description. Just remove that shortcut from that action.

[image]